# Event ID 5586 on SP Foundation and SQL Express

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have a brand new Hyper-V VM with Windows 2012, fully updated up to today (11 Sept 2013). I installed SharePoint Foundation 2013 and additionally MS SQL Express 2012 on the same instance.

In my event viewer I have 4 records of the same critical error:
Event ID 5586
Unknown SQL exception -2146893055 occurred. Additional information from SQL Server is included below.
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The handle specified is invalid)

The internet has nothing like this and I don't know what went wrong on a brand new machine.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a login issue with SQL, possibly the service. Are you able to login to the instance using Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, I can log in. I can also start the SharePoint site I created and it works.